# javascript linking and ordering strings to arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a set of arrays which looks like below when being called form php into javascript data element.

```
for($index =0; $index < 100; $index++
data-example2 = "'htmlspecialchars(json_encode($ExampleArray[$index][28]), ENT_Quotes, 'CP1252')
...
```

"$ExampleArray[$index][28]" - returns

```
Array (
   [0] => Example Text 1
    )
Array (
   [0] => Example Text 2
   [1] => Example Text 3
   [2] => Example Text 4
   [3] => Example Text 5
     )
Array (
   [0] => Example Text 6
   [1] => Example Text 7
       )
```

etc, etc
There are four data entries being passed, for example

```
$ExampleArray[$index][28], $ExampleArray[$index][29], $ExampleArray[$index][30], $ExampleArray[$index][31]
```

Their values entries match with eachother. For example

$ExampleArray[$index][28], the first array[0] matches with

$ExampleArray[$index][29] array [0],

$ExampleArray[$index][30] array[0],

$ExampleArray[$index][31] array[0],

In my java script i am setting variables for each ex...

```
$exOne =  $(this).data("example");
$exTwo = $(this).data("example2");
$exThree = $(this).data("example3");
$exFour = $(this).data("example4");
```

exOne are dates so i have a sort function to list them from newest to oldest

```
$exTwo = $exTwo.sort().reverse();
```

Then i am using a function to help put this data into a table

```
$exOne.forEach(function(value, key){
        let firstExample = $exOne[key],
        secondExample = $exTwo[key]?$exTwo[key]:"",
        thirdExample = $exThree[key]?$exThree[key]:"",
        fourthExample = $exFour[key]?$exFour[key]:"";
```

The issues is when i order exOne(the array full of dates), it messes up the matching of all the other data. If i didn't not have to order exOne, everything aligns perfectly.

Also I did a

console.log(type of secondExample) * the others as well and they are all coming up as string types.

Comment: I don't really see why this is tagged PHP, as the PHP code you have is seemingly unrelated as you haven't posted it here.

Comment: The php is the first bit of code i created, and the initial array is in php.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying it's unrelated to your actual question though.

Comment: Instead of providing the PHP intro, it would be more useful if you would provide actual content of the JavaScript variables, produce a fiddle with it, and say what exactly in the fiddle's output you don't like, and provide the desired output, based on the sample data.

Comment: But it must be said that if things belong together and they are spread over different arrays you are making your life unnecessarily difficult. Put things that belong together, together in one (associative) array (i.e. object in JS)